# Use a struct in another struct

Tags: c++, struct

Hi there I keep getting error for the code below which I think makes sense!
I'm trying to use a member of the first struct in a function in the second struct. I code in Xcode and this is the error I get:

> No member named 'PLZ' in 'std::__1::vector >'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct place {
    string PLZ;
    string name;
};
struct adresse {
    string firstN;
    string lastN;
    string Str;
    string Hsnum;
    string PLZ;
    void print(vector<place> a){

       cout<<a.PLZ;
    }
};
int main()
{

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` is `std::vector`, not `place`.

Comment: A `vector<place>` contains some number of `place`. Which of those `place`'s `PLZ` are you trying to print?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh! you're right! I get it now thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the function at least like

```
void print(const vector<place> &a) const
{
    for ( const auto &place : a )
    {
        cout << place.PLZ << ' ';
    }
}
```

`std::vector` is a container that can contain several elements. So you have to specify whether you are going to output all elements of a vector or a concrete element.

The function above outputs the data member `PLZ` of each element of the vector.